# An uncommon variant of 写

Tags: kanji

I ran into the sentence below. The meaning is clear and when copying and pasting the *kanji* I get: 写. I wonder how common such a form of the *kanji* is. Is it just a different font?

[image]

Comment: See: [Han Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing a Mainland Chinese font.

[image]

The Mainland Chinese shape is out of place with the others, and was influenced by the common shape of「与」, for which the Japanese shape is out of place with the others.

[image]

> 「真」is different too.
>
> [image]

Note,「写」and「与」are completely unrelated characters.

---

*Source: zdic*

Comment: The 糹radical in 綺 is different as well.